# latex bug in the part title between the number and title

Tags: format, latex

the label of the title and number are overlapping and I have 0 experience with latex,
the sty file I believe to be sections.sty

in the text is a simple: \part{Part Tres: NPCs}

but in the sty is

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%% \part

\titleformat{\part}
[display]
{\thispagestyle{part}\nodesto\fontsize{50pt}{50pt}\selectfont\color{title1}\filcenter}
{\partname \thepart}
{-15pt}
{\Large}

\titlespacing*{\part}{0pt}{-54pt}{0pt}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%% \chapter
```

[image]

Comment: I haven't the solution. But if unluckily none has it, you may try to ask, after, the dedicated _Latex_ _Stack Exchange_ community: https://tex.stackexchange.com/